# Как выполнить запрос к Google Analytics Reporting API?

Tags: php, google-analytics

Доброго времени суток!

Есть задача: связать посетителя сайта с данными, которые собрала по нему google analytics.
Нашёл отличное решение, которое мне идеально [подходит](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/user-reporting#making_a_user_activity_request).
Проблема в том, что я не понимаю как мне запрос из примера выполнить из PHP.

Вот тут код из примера введения в это всё дело, может быть как-то поможет

```
    function getReport($analytics) {

  // Replace with your view ID, for example XXXX.
  $VIEW_ID = "<REPLACE_WITH_VIEW_ID>";

  // Create the DateRange object.
  $dateRange = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
  $dateRange->setStartDate("7daysAgo");
  $dateRange->setEndDate("today");

  // Create the Metrics object.
  $sessions = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
  $sessions->setExpression("ga:sessions");
  $sessions->setAlias("sessions");

  // Create the ReportRequest object.
  $request = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
  $request->setViewId($VIEW_ID);
  $request->setDateRanges($dateRange);
  $request->setMetrics(array($sessions));

  $body = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();
  $body->setReportRequests( array( $request) );
  return $analytics->reports->batchGet( $body );
}
```